# Prolog Member in Logic Puzzles

Tags: prolog, zebra-puzzle

I'm new to Prolog and need some guidance *(not answers) to get in the right direction. Firstly, I'm trying to solve a logic puzzle. There are triples in the logic. I know  how to create negations and members like the following:

```
member ([_, X, _], Triples ),
\+ member([_, X, Y], Triples).
```

Where I am stuck and not quite understanding Prolog is how to compare members (using inequalities) based on their relationships. For example, X was eaten later in the week than the Y.

```
Given an unknown "_" [_,X,_], I want to make sure [_,X,_] is greater than [_,Y,_].
```

So I have tried

```
([_,X,_], Triple) > ([_,Y,_], Triple),
```

But it  doesn't seem to work?

Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: Not quite sure what you want to achieve. There should be an ordering on the triples, but what is `([_,X,_], Triple)` and how does term like ([_,X,_], Triple) > ([_,Y,_], Triple),` and why is there a comma at the end? Post some code.

Comment: Please refer to [tag:zebra-puzzle], you will find there various ways to model this  dependence.